# TortoiseSVN update file from different path

Tags: svn, filesystems, tortoisesvn

I was just wondering if this is possible using TortoiseSVN:

I have a file living in one directory in the repository, let's say:

```
\\repo\work_branch\bin\Important.dll
```

This file gets updated whenever it needs to be, but always at this location in the repository.

I have another folder, containing a different executable, i.e:

```
\\repo\program_2\bin\
```

What I would like to have happen is that whenever a user grabs what's under `\\repo\program_2\bin\`, they also get Important.dll from the path specified above.

I.e. I don't want to have to place Important.dll inside '\repo\program_2\bin\' but still want the user to get what is essentially a copy of it when they grab that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. svn:external can do that for you.  if you're on 1.6.x or higher you can do it on a single file, 1.5 only works on directories.  The syntax for file externals is:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html

You want to be very sure that you use an explicit revision as the target of your external.  A tag is preferable, but a repo revision will work.  The goal is to be able to reproduce an older build - if you set your external to the trunk, you may get a new version of Important.dll if you rebuild from an older tag.

In the java world there is some stellar tooling to deal with this very case - maven and ivy do a really good job of dependency management. I've never successfully done anything similar for .NET - but I strongly recommend you check into it.  http://refix.codeplex.com http://nathanmarz.com/blog/introducing-nanny-a-really-simple-dependency-management-tool.html may be worht some research.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately we only use 1.5.2, and aren't looking to upgrade at any point in the near future. Not such an issue though, I'll move things around to grab entire directories.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `svn externals` - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html.

You can have an external from  `\\repo\program_2\bin\` to `\\repo\work_branch\bin\`